# How I can Gave The Variable To The Array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to solve a problem, I have one integer variable such as

```
unsigned int x = 456;
```

Now I want to decompose my integer to an array of its digits, like so:

```
unsigned int i[] = {4,5,6};
```

Then I want to convert each element of the array to a string or char.
Any ideas?

I use Avr studio

Comment: What do you think you need to do?

Comment: You fogort to post the code where you already tried to print it. Surely those two lines are not your complete attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned int x = 456;
    int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%u", x);
    unsigned int i[len];
    unsigned int wk = x;
    for(int k=len-1;k>=0;--k, wk/=10)
        i[k]=wk % 10;
    for(int k=0;k<len;++k)
        printf("%u", i[k]);

    char string[len+1];
    for(int k=0;k<len;++k)
        sprintf(string+k, "%u", i[k]);
    printf("\n%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could use a variable when declaring an array in a function. I guess I tried it on a global once really early on when learning C, and promptly (and erroneously) declared to myself to never use variables in array declarations.

Comment: @Jsor i use c99 compiler.

Comment: C99 allows arrays to be initialized by using variables or to have an unspecified length an to be immediately initialized with an array literal (from which the compiler may infer the actual length of the array).

Comment: C11 allows for structures to have an array field of unspecified length (only if it is the very last field in the struct declaration). When initializing such a structure from a literal the compiler knows how to allocate memory for it. When allocating dynamic memory for it it is your duty to allocate the proper storage space. In both cases it is your duty avoid going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert an integer to a string is to use a library function such as `snprintf()`.

If you don't have the standard C library, you can use the classic remainder/division trick:

```
void uint_to_string(char *buf, unsigned int x, unsigned int digits)
{
  buf[digits] = '\0';
  while(digits > 0)
  {
    buf[--digits] = '0' + (x % 10);
    x /= 10;
  }
}
```

Note that the above builds the string "backwards" (right to left) since that's easiest. It will generate a 0-padded result, you can fix that by adding code to `break` out of the loop (after the digit is generated on the first line of the loop's body) if `x == 0`.

Comment: Nitpick: this assumes that you already know the number of digits. Finding the value is easy (it's almost the exact same loop, in fact), but having it is not a given.

Comment: @Jsor I thought that was a given, since the question uses three digits. :) But yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
    unsigned int x = 456;
    char i[3];
    int j,k;
    for (j=0; x!=0; j++){
       i[j] = x%10 + '0';
       x /= 10;
    }
    for (k=0; k<j; k++)
       printf("%c ", i[k]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are doing in your code. Just firing out code snippets doesn't help the OP learn.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is slightly dependent on your actual problem. Do you *need* the array of digits, or is this merely the intermediate step you yourself came up with to convert an unsigned integer to a string?

If all you need is the string, it would be much simpler to use a function such as sprintf or snprintf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//...
unsigned int x = 456;
char digits[50]; // 50 is chosen arbitrarily
snprintf(digits, 50, "%u", x);
//...
```

Will yield a null-terminated string in digits that looks exactly like the string representation of x, with the caveat that if x is more than 50 digits it will just do as much as it can. (Though I'm not sure an unsigned int can even have more than 50 decimal digits off the top of my head)

If you want the char* to be exactly the correct size to hold the number, it's only a little more difficult.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ...
unsigned int x = 456;
int numDigits = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%u", x); // snprintf returns the number of characters that could potentially be written.
char digits[numDigits];

sprintf(digits, "%u", x);
// ...
```

Without the standard library available, it gets a bit more hairy, but not unmanageably so. Unfortunately, you're going to need two passes that do almost exactly the same things: one to count the digits and one to actually assign them to your array.

```
int main( void ) {
    // ...
    unsigned int x = 456;
    int numDigits = countDigits(x);
    char digits[numDigits+1]; // The +1 is for null-termination
    fillDigitArray(digits, x, numDigits);
    // ...
}

int fillDigitArray(char *digits, int x, int numDigits) {
   int i;

    // This requires perhaps a little explaining
    // By far the easiest way to get individual digits of a number is with
    // x % 10, but this gives us the righthand-most digits
    // Thus by counting DOWN, we're filling our buffer from the RIGHT
    // making up for the "backwards" nature. 
    digits[numDigits] = 0;
    for (i = numDigits-1; i >= 0; i--) {
       digits[i]  = '0' + (x%10);
       x /= 10;
    }
}

int countDigits(int x) {
    // Special case
    if( x == 0 ) {
       return 1;
    }
    int numDigits;
    while(x > 0) {
         x /= 10;
         numDigits++;
    }

    return numDigits;
}
```

Extracting it into an array of `unsigned int`s is similar, just make digits an `unsigned int *` rather than a `char *`, and instead of making `digits[i] = '0' + x%10` make it `digits[i] = x%10`.

Edit: In the interest of fully explaining the example, `x%10` is "x mod 10", which can roughly be stated as "give me the rightmost digit of x". `x /= 10`, while dividing x by 10 and overwriting x with the new value, is essentially just our way of saying "make the right-most digit of x what is currently in the 10's place".

The `'0'+ x%10` part is admittedly a bit of magic. The actual ASCII character value for the number "0" isn't actually 0, but the digits 0-9 are laid out in order. So if the rightmost digits of x is 0, we get `'0'+0`, which is '0', and if we get the rightmost digit as 9 `'0'+9'` becomes '9'. Using this allows us to bypass an ugly if or switch statement to map the number to the right character.

Answer (score -1):

Getting each digit is a math/logic problem. You need to use the modulus operator which gives you the remainder of the division of the operands.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char digits[10];

int main(void) {
    int number      = 4056;
    int remainder   = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while(number > 0 && digits[i] >= 0) {
        remainder   = number % 10;
        number      /= 10;
        digits[i]   = 48 + remainder;

        i++;
    }

    for(i--; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", digits[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This code has a bug, number%10 gets the rightmost digit, while this fills from the left. It will successfully decompose the number into its digits, but the resulting array will be backwards. (It also unsuccessfully handles the case where number == 0)

Comment: On further review, this is completely broken. You never update number with `number /= 10` (or otherwise), so this code will just write the number "6" in the array 10 times and then either corrupt memory or segfault.

Comment: @Jsor On your first comment: the fact that the array would be inversed is true but I intended it to be read in reverse. I wanted this because if the `digits[10]` array would be static (guaranteed to be zeroed) it would allow you to obtain the digits for integers of any number of digits between 1 and 10 by checking if the next value is 0 or not.

Comment: @Jsor On your second comment: I think the word you're looking for is "incomplete". Yes, yes it is incomplete -- intendedly. Because this question looks like homework and I like to give students just enough to get them going. After a while I update my answer with further explanations for completeness (and future reference).

Comment: I also did not include a `main` prototype, nor did I include the actual conversion of the integer to char. My intent was to provide the "student" the mathematical/logical idea of obtaining the digit by using the `remainder of division`. The rest is his job.